# Rails date_select and update_attributes

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm about to tear my hair out, so I must be missing something basic...

I have the following form (simplified):

```
<%= form_for(@public_call) do |f| %>
<div>Start: <%= f.date_select(:start_date,:start_year=>Time.now.year) -%></div>
<div>End: <%= f.date_select(:end_date,:start_year=>Time.now.year) -%></div>
<div>Deadline: <%= f.datetime_select(:submission_deadline,:start_year=>Time.now.year-1) -%></div>
<%- end -%>
```

The form posts to the following method (simplified):

```
def update
  begin
    @public_call = PublicCall.find(params[:id])
    @public_call.update_attributes!(params[:public_call])
  rescue
    ...
  end
end
```

Submitting the form results in the following being reported by the Rails logger (simplified):

```
Parameters:
  {"public_call"=>
    {"start_date(1i)"=>"2012",
     "start_date(2i)"=>"9",
     "start_date(3i)"=>"30",
     "end_date(1i)"=>"2012",
     "end_date(2i)"=>"10",
     "end_date(3i)"=>"3",
     "submission_deadline(1i)"=>"2012",
     "submission_deadline(2i)"=>"4",
     "submission_deadline(3i)"=>"27",
     "submission_deadline(4i)"=>"23",
     "submission_deadline(5i)"=>"59"}
  }
```

Here's the problem: Rails doesn't seem to be translating the parameters for the three fields into date and datetime objects for the database, like it's supposed to. The query reported by the Rails logger is:

```
UPDATE `public_calls` SET `start_date`=NULL, `end_date`=NULL, `submission_deadline`=NULL, `updated_at`='2012-03-20 20:47:15' WHERE...
```

Any idea what gives?

BTW, Rails 3.2.0 / Ruby 1.9.3. None of my attributes on the public_calls model are protected.

Thanks!

EDIT

Also tried using the :without_protection option with update_attributes! but that doesn't work either.

EDIT #2

I've tried debugging what's going on in ActiveRecord's AttributeAssignment module as follows:

```
def assign_multiparameter_attributes(pairs)
  Rails.logger.info('ASSIGN_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: '+pairs.inspect)
  execute_callstack_for_multiparameter_attributes(
    extract_callstack_for_multiparameter_attributes(pairs)
  )
end

def execute_callstack_for_multiparameter_attributes(callstack)
  errors = []
  Rails.logger.info('EXECUTE_CALLSTACK_FOR_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: '+callstack.inspect)
  callstack.each do |name, values_with_empty_parameters|
    begin
      send(name + "=", read_value_from_parameter(name, values_with_empty_parameters))
    rescue => ex
      errors << AttributeAssignmentError.new("error on assignment #{values_with_empty_parameters.values.inspect} to #{name}", ex, name)
    end
  end
  unless errors.empty?
    raise MultiparameterAssignmentErrors.new(errors), "#{errors.size} error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes"
  end
end

def extract_callstack_for_multiparameter_attributes(pairs)
  Rails.logger.info('EXTRACT_CALLSTACK_FOR_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: '+pairs.inspect)
  attributes = { }
  pairs.each do |pair|
    multiparameter_name, value = pair
    attribute_name = multiparameter_name.split("(").first
    attributes[attribute_name] = {} unless attributes.include?(attribute_name)
    parameter_value = value.empty? ? nil : type_cast_attribute_value(multiparameter_name, value)
    attributes[attribute_name][find_parameter_position(multiparameter_name)] ||= parameter_value
  end
  Rails.logger.info('EXTRACT_CALLSTACK_FOR_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: '+attributes.inspect)
  attributes
end
```

And here's what I get:

```
ASSIGN_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: [["start_date(1i)", "2012"], ["start_date(2i)", "9"], ["start_date(3i)", "30"], ["end_date(1i)", "2012"], ["end_date(2i)", "10"], ["end_date(3i)", "3"], ["submission_deadline(1i)", "2012"], ["submission_deadline(2i)", "4"], ["submission_deadline(3i)", "27"], ["submission_deadline(4i)", "23"], ["submission_deadline(5i)", "59"]]
EXTRACT_CALLSTACK_FOR_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: [["start_date(1i)", "2012"], ["start_date(2i)", "9"], ["start_date(3i)", "30"], ["end_date(1i)", "2012"], ["end_date(2i)", "10"], ["end_date(3i)", "3"], ["submission_deadline(1i)", "2012"], ["submission_deadline(2i)", "4"], ["submission_deadline(3i)", "27"], ["submission_deadline(4i)", "23"], ["submission_deadline(5i)", "59"]]
EXTRACT_CALLSTACK_FOR_MULTIPARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES: {"start_date"=>{1=>2012, 2=>9, 3=>30}, "end_date"=>{1=>2012, 2=>10, 3=>3}, "submission_deadline"=>{1=>2012, 2=>4, 3=>27, 4=>23, 5=>59}}
```

Any ideas why the execute_callstack_for_multiparameter_attributes method isn't getting called?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your rails version - I was having the same problem, moving from v 3.2.0 to v 3.2.8 solved it for me.

Comment: Is there anything in rails changelog regarding these methods?